# c function definition calls for pointer but example does not use pointers

Tags: c, pointers, strstr

I relatively new to low level programming such as c. I am reviewing the strstr() function [here](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strstr-function/). When reviewing the function definition `char *strstr(const char *str1, const char *str2);` I understand that function will return a pointer or a NULL depending if str2 was found in str1.

What I can't understand though, is if the funciton requires the two inputs to be pointers, when does the example not use pointers?

```
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
  char string[55] ="This is a test string for testing";
  char *p;
  p = strstr (string,"test");
  if(p)
  {
    printf("string found\n" );
    printf ("First occurrence of string \"test\" in \"%s\" is"\
           " \"%s\"",string, p);
  }
  else printf("string not found\n" );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strings are arrays. And arrays become (decay to) pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: Why do you think this example does not use pointers?  `string` is a `char *`, as is `"test"`.  (Rather `string` is a char array, which decays to a `char *`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `strstr(string,"test");`, `string` is an array of 55 `char`. What `strstr` needs here is a pointer to the first element of `string`, which we can write as `&string[0]`. However, as a convenience, C automatically converts `string` to a pointer to its first element. So the desired value is passed to `strstr`, and it is a pointer.

This automatic conversion happens whenever an array is used in an expression and is not the operand of `sizeof`, is not the operand of unary `&`, and is not a string literal used to initialize an array.

`"test"` is a string literal. It causes the creation of an array of `char` initialized with the characters in the string, followed by a terminating null character. The string literal in source code represents that array. Since it is an array used in an expression, it too is converted to a pointer to its first element. So, again, the desired pointer is passed to `strstr`.

You could instead write `&"test"[0]`, but that would confuse people who are not used to it.